How can I repeatedly update a variable in my sympy summation?
I have a sympy summation in python, and I am currently using a variable that is repeatedly updated each time I say it. It's called result.
In my summation, I want to be able to perform this action where the variable is updated each time it runs, but in each step of my summation. I will show you what I am talking about.
The code I'm using is:
from sympy import symbols, summation, Piecewise, invert

x = symbols("n")


def add(P1_c, P2_c, p, k):
    if P1_c == 0:
        return P2_c  # P1 is the point at infinity
    if P2_c == 0:
        return P1_c  # P2 is the point at infinity
    x1 = P1_c % k
    y1 = P1_c // k
    x2 = P2_c % k
    y2 = P2_c // k
    if x1 == x2 and y1 != y2:
        return 0
    if x1 == x2 and y1 == y2:
        m = (3 * x1**2 * invert(2 * y1, p)) % p
    else:
        m = ((y2 - y1) * invert(x2 - x1, p)) % p
    x3 = (m**2 - x1 - x2) % p
    y3 = (m * (x1 - x3) - y1) % p
    # Return combined number
    return x3 + k * y3


def multiply(P_c, scalar, p, k, n):
    result = 0  # Point at infinity (neutral element)
    current = P_c
    result = add(result, current, p, k)
    result = add(result, current, p, k)
    result = add(result, current, p, k)
    # result = point_add(result,current,p,k)
    # uncomment to see different results
    m = Piecewise((result, True))
    return result


k = 2**256
p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
Gx, Gy = (
    0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798,
    0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8)

G_c = Gx + k * Gy
logic = multiply(G_c, x, p, k, x)

result2 = summation(logic, (x, 1, 1))
print(result2)

As you can see, in my code, in the Multiply function, the result variable has to be stated multiple times in order for it to be updated. I want to be able to update it automatically with each step of my summation.
I want you guys to help me use the piecewise inside the Multiply function that performs this behavior for me.
I want the result variable to be repeatedly updated one at a time for each step in my summation instead of saying it explicitly like I did in the multiply function.

please fix the indentation levels

Where do you call the add() function and what is summation()?

Do you mean you want to preload the possible values in Piecewise and then use these during the summation?
>>> def multiply(P_c, scalar, p, k, n):
...     result = 0  # Point at infinity (neutral element)
...     current = P_c
...     args = []
...     for do in range(1,n+1):
...         args.append((result, Eq(x,do)))
...         result = add(result, current, p, k)
...     args.append((result, Eq(x,do)))
...     return Piecewise(*args)
...
>>>
>>> k = 2**256
>>> p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
>>> Gx, Gy = (
...     0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798,
...     0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8)
>>>
>>> G_c = Gx + k * Gy

Here is where the preload up to level 5 is going to happen
>>> logic = multiply(G_c, x, p, k, 5)

And here it is being used:
>>> result2 = summation(logic, (x, 1, 5))
>>> print(result2)
12444069121702127148818957969634912142775749049935936604898840370927481565648533170696439913195367562630688913151027647099019996465189323213074674979027593

And this is what the logic looked like
>>> logic
Piecewise(
(0, Eq(x, 1)), 
(3782986611752337923735041210995345251997213050810892522976501834283283045527942703301965451480245841739956145498438496665055223218014813005524252965214104, Eq(x, 2)), 
(1407846456693070737751936883740874794908898493761359132808354728722630139714824837073748230882575968019751922328527167185629665268681065306856146888335077, Eq(x, 3)), 
(2962312258887020902996829409547555946427980494815929668543025376556350081229431596346848702979946648176962311661940508790404171419341323165548996940805881, Eq(x, 4)), 
(4290923794369697584335150465351136149441657010547755280570958431365218299176334033973877527852599104694018533662121474457930936559152121735145278184672531, Eq(x, 5)))


If this is what you want, I think memoize decoration of the add function would be the way to go. You don't need Piecewise to hold the results for you -- you can let Python keep track of the function values as they are generated, I think. I don't use that mcuh but that should point you in a direction to use that feature instead of Piecewise.
